# I get some troubles with post and save serializer

Tags: python, django, post, serialization

serializers.py:

```
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
class Meta:
    model = Snippet
    fields = ('id', 'title','owner', 'code', 'linenos', 'language', 'style')

def create(self, validated_data):
    owner=validated_data.pop('owner')
    try:
        owner=User.objects.get(username=owner)
        snippet=Snippet.objects.create(owner=owner,**validated_data)
        return snippet
    except:
        return Http404
```

view.py:

```
class SnippetList(APIView):
"""
List all snippets, or create a new snippet.
"""
permission_classes =     (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)
def get(self, request, format=None):
    snippets = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippets, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)


def post(self, request, format=None):
    data=request.data
    data['owner']=request.user
    serializer = SnippetSerializer(data=data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Models:

```
class Snippet(models.Model):
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
code = models.TextField()
linenos = models.BooleanField(default=False)
language = models.CharField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, default='python', max_length=100)
style = models.CharField(choices=STYLE_CHOICES, default='friendly', max_length=100)
owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
highlighted = models.TextField()
```

Post data:

```
{
    "title": "dfhhtryres",
    "owner": "admin",
    "code": "hfdsadfghdfh",
    "linenos": false,
    "language": "python",
    "style": "friendly"
}
```

> Error: KeyError at /snippets/ 'owner'

Comment: You need to edit your question to include the full stacktrace of your error. We couldn't find your error by just looking at the code.

Comment: sorry ,my question's ambiguous, I wrote it at the end of my post